# filter CoreData attributes to unique and show them on UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

hello my app shows list of cities(streets)  which are grouped in countries. 
when i save a new street, it looks like this:

```
Country -> USA
City-> New York
street-> timeSqaure
```

when i save another street like this:

```
Country -> USA
City-> New York
street-> 233 street 330 west
```

my TableView duplicates the City [Screenshot](http://i42.tinypic.com/1e019j.jpg)

how can i filter the duplicated city to a unique city.

my fetch looks like this:

```
-(void) performFetch
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [app managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Country" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [request setEntity:entity];


    NSSortDescriptor *sort1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"country" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sort1, nil];

    [request setSortDescriptors:sortArray];

    NSError *error;

    self.fetchedResultsController =[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:@"country" cacheName:nil];

    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my problem.  i just set another entity named "street" with a one to many relationship. and it works like charm